# selenium webdriver - report generating, taking screenshot and save to folder on desktop

Tags: error-handling, selenium-webdriver, report, screenshot, testng

After generating a script in selenium webdriver using testng framework, how to generate test report, error handling, taking screenshot and save to folder on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Code for taking screenshot and save to folder on desktop.

```
public static void ScreenShot() throws IOException {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//Takes screenshot
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    // Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
    String path;
    path = "C:/Users/owner/Desktop/screenshots/" + scrFile.getName();//goes to the path and automatically gives name
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(path)); //copies the screenshot file to the given path.

}
```